# Where I can download the REAL Full .Net Framework 4 Standalone Installer?

Tags: .net-4.0

I found that links:

1. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Web Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en)
2. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7)
3. [Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (Standalone Installer)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E5AD0459-CBCC-4B4F-97B6-FB17111CF544&displaylang=en)

Note that (2) the size is 48.0 MB and the (3) the size is 41.0 MB. It's not the REAL .Net 4 Full Standalone. :(

I want that installer in a usb pen drive because my app need of features of **.Net 4 Full Framework (like MSBuild)** and I will install in a enviroment without Internet access.

PS: I tested the (2) and really is the Client Profile with another name... :(

Comment: Well done, you've picked 4 tags never seen before. That's a great way to subvert SO's classifications...

Comment: @skaffman: and you removed all tags to another fully generic and unuseful tag...

Comment: Tags are *supposed* to be generic and broad, they're there for classifying questions. Narrow tags that noone knows about are useless.

Comment: Agreed with skaffman ~ Try and use the ones that are already in the autocomplete, it helps people like me later ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, you already found the full .NET 4 SDK. Microsoft put in a lot of effort to decrease the size.

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4
>   redistributable package installs the
>   .NET Framework runtime and associated
>   files that are required to run and
>   develop applications to target the
>   .NET Framework 4.

Have a look at this [hanselpost](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TowardsASmallerNET4DetailsOnTheClientProfileAndDownloadingNET.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The prerequisites have changed since .NET 3.5 SP1, .NET 4.0 requires at least XP SP3,  Windows 2003 SP2 or Vista SP1.  .NET 3.5 could be installed on *any* version of these operating systems, including a 11 year old completely unpatched version of XP.

So the 3.5 installer also needs to be able to update a bunch of native Windows components.

Not having to include the Windows component updates and additions allowed for a significant size reduction.  If that's an issue then you'll have to include the Windows service pack installers on your pen drive.